# <a> Tag Responding Differently To <div>

Tags: html, css, tags, anchor

Sorry for the title but I didn't quite know how to word this.

I have a html document for a web page that I'm creating and I've been using `<div>` tags to set out the structure of the page and everything looks fine. However, when I change the `<div>` tags to `<a>` tags they dissappear unless they are floated left (and possibly right). Does anyone know why this is and how to make the `<a>` tags work without having to float them?

Comment: some code or fiddle will make question useful.

Comment: `<div>` are block elements and `<a>` are inline-elements. For valid HTML `<a>` should be nested within a block element. Otherwise, if you don't care about validation, then just add `display: block` under your `a` in your css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `div` tags are block level elements and `a` tags are inline level elements.

When you float the `a` elements, their display behavior becomes block level.

This is standard behavior as defined in the CSS2 specification.

If you wanted to work around this, you would need to apply `display: block` to the relevant `a` tags.

Note that as of HTML5, you can next a block level element within an `a` tag.

Comment: Ah yes of course, I completely forgot about them being inline. I've changed the CSS to `display: block` and all is working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`<div>` tags are rendered in a fundamentally-different way to `<a>` tags: divs are block tags, but anchors are inline.

Try setting the following CSS on the anchors you're using:

```
display: block;
```

As stated below, adding a float forces the render mode to block and therefore has the same effect.